# How to apply $regexMatch to an object field that's nested inside an object with the MongoDB Aggregation pipeline?

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, eve

Is there a way I can build an aggregation pipeline stage to do a `$regexMatch` on an object field nested within another object. I typically see examples using the `$addFields` aggregation pipeline stage, so I've been trying to do a match with this stage. I'm trying to do a search on the word `word` within the `string_text` field of each object.

**Note: This needs to be done in the domain file when building the aggregation pipeline.**

Here is an example of the data I'm trying to do a `$regexMatch` on, in this case the `text` field:

```
{
    array_of_data: [
        textObjects: {
            text1: {
                string_text: "Matching word here"      
            },
            text2: {
                string_text: "Looking for the matching word which is here"     
            },
            text3: {
                string_text: "Won't find it here"    
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I've been trying to build it solve this issue with a `$filter` operation, but still don't get the results I'm looking for, it returns every document and not the ones with the word `word` in the `string_text` field.

**Any help would be appreciated, I've been struggling with this for a few days now :(**

Comment: Use the dot notation: {'foo.bar' => {$regex: ...}}

Comment: @D.SM I' building this aggregation pipeline in the domain file for this specific collection

Comment: What does that have to do with dot notation?